# How to find special characters like U+202A in an Excel file?

Tags: excel, xlsx

I am working with arabic and latin characters in an Excel files. I wonder how to find special character like LEFT-TO-RIGHT mark (U+202A) in  Microsoft Excel.

I dind't find a way to do that. Only have the oportunity to find especial characters going to a Hexadecimal program and try to find the hex char.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Go to Insert -> Symbol.

You'll get a window practically identical to the windows character map. You can even search by character code if you want, find the relevant supported font and type 202A into the "Character Code" box.

Comment: The real problem is to find a special character inside the text of an Excel file. I don't know how to do it.

Comment: Sorry just saw this, unfortunately the only way I can think of doing this straight up from the keyboard would be to type 202a and then immediately after that hold ctrl+alt+shift+F12 or alt+shift+x, this works in Wordpad but I don't know about Excel or Word.

Answer (score 0):

This will pick up any ASCII characters in selected range and write it in the cell next to it:

```
Sub Button1_Click()
Dim cell As Range

For Each cell In Selection
    'Find cells with special chars
    specialChars = False
    For i = 1 To Len(cell.Value)
        If (Asc(Mid(cell, i, 1)) >= 128) Then
            specialChars = True
        End If
    Next

    'Where to copy cell
    If (specialChars = True) Then
        cell.Offset(0, 1).Value = cell.Value
    End If
Next cell
End Sub
```

Comment: Excel—and `Asc`—don't use ASCII. But, U+202A isn't ASCII anyway. If VBA is a possible solution for @StanVest, try `ChrW(&H202A)` or `AscW(…)` as applicable. They use UTF-16. (`Asc` is a really odd animal, which should be avoided except when it is exactly what is wanted.)

Comment: Yeah, as I suspected, `Debug.Print Asc(ChrW(&H202A))` prints 33, which is the character code for the applicable (on my system, for me, right now) replacement character (i.e., ?).